# Kendo MVVM value binding character encoding

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

How can i disable character encoding in kendo mvvm value binding? I have already encoded string and trying to bind it

```
<input name='myText' data-bind='value: MyText'></input>
```

but i get codes of letters instead of normal text value. How can i prevent double encoding in this example?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the encoding at the value binding phase. The change needs to be made at the viewmodel level. Easiest way would be to create a property, say 'MyText1' and bind it to that instead.